# High Frequency/Performance computing questions?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Is it possible with the number of latency/performance/HF questions asked on Stack Overflow and programmers exchange to create a place whereby performance enthusiasts can ask questions?

How is this possible/is it do-able?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why wouldn't [su] suit?

Comment: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137131/102937) for some lulz.

Comment: As in consumer performance enthusiasts, I assume? [scicomp.se] is available for computational science methods, but of course they won't tell you how to overclock your CPU/ect

Comment: Questions like Java vs C++, micro-optimisations, FPGA, GPGPU programming etc. I dont mean overclocking- I mean writing fast code and possibly the hardware it runs on. I am thinking more towards scientific programming and finance.

Answer (score 4):

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where new sites are proposed and brought to life if it gathers enough support.

Sites which may be relevant:

- [High Performance Computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19888/high-performance-computing) - still needs more example questions before it can move on to the next stage.
- [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) - public beta. See [HPC](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hpc) and [performance](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tags.
- [Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com) - public beta. see [high-frequency](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-frequency) and [HFT](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hft) tags.

Comment: The quantitative finance site only allows HF questions regarding financial theory- not technical programming/hardware questions.