# Asking a tag question/question tag or opposite yes/no question to avoid getting downvotes for a 'no' answer or other 'rejection'

Tags: discussion, down-votes, feature-request-process

I read some meta posts that are yes/no questions often use downvotes to indicate a 'no' answer even if the question is good. I don't know about [Christianity SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/are-we-ready-for-catholicism-se/), but I recall I read they do that on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

**What's stopping people then from rephrasing questions to get the opposite answer like to make the 'rejection' answer to be 'yes' ?**

Let's say for the above 'Are we ready for Catholicism.SE?' It might be rephrased to, not necessarily tag questions/question tags like 'Aren't we ready for Catholicism.SE?' (which unfortunately in the English language and even other languages like Philippine/[Tagalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagalog_language) or Japanese is often *incorrectly* treated as no different from the original), but like 'Are we unprepared for Catholicism.SE?'

It seems that the answers will be exact opposite, but the reasons for the answers will basically be the same (for example, citing statistics). And more importantly...

**The rephrasing doesn't seem to have any risk.** While the original phrasing runs the risk of 'No, we're not ready. Are you insane?', I don't think anyone will say like 'No, we are so prepared! We have so many posts about this or that. Are you insane? Do you hate Catholics or the Catholic church?' (unless there was like another meta post on the topic in which case the post will just get closed as duplicate or maybe not even made at all). It seems like people will just say either 'Yes, you're absolutely right. Your guess is correct.' or 'No, actually, I think we're doing pretty good. Let's get mod X here to be a mod there.' **And do you really think people will or should downvote the question in the latter case?**

Arguably, the rephrasing could be seen as humble or something while the original phrasing is like seen as arrogant or [ignorantly/naively](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112778/ignorantly-dishonest/579061#579061)/immaturely excited or something. **But then why don't we just give the [BOTD](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BOTD#Noun) and not see the original phrasing as arrogant or whatever (namely by not downvoting as a no answer)? Ignore** this paragraph if this case is not about humility vs arrogance.

However, I guess by [Cunningham's Law](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/update-yes-or-cunninghams-law-joke-answers-allowed-seriously) (Btw, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375259/are-some-stackexchange-sites-really-allowed-joke-answers)), the original phrasing does get more response. I guess it depends on how brave you are to face '[rejection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjhf0lBHFHY)'(-[sensitive dysphoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM3azhiOy5E)).

P.S. To be clear I'm not even asking a yes/no question. I'm ***not*** asking (unconditionally) 'Should we stop this policy?' or even, like, oh IDK, 'Is this policy extremely good that we should keep continuing it?' (LOL) **I'm just asking what's stopping people from rephrasing their questions to make the 'rejection' answer to be yes.** So, a fortiori, this isn't even a yes/no question.

P.P.S. I actually tried this on [Chess SE](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/update-yes-or-cunninghams-law-joke-answers-allowed-seriously). (Btw, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375259/are-some-stackexchange-sites-really-allowed-joke-answers).)

P.P.P.S. This above of course applies to feature requests in general. I recall seeing on some meta of SE sites like there's even like a status-declined tag or something to feature requests. Viewing this tag as a rejection, I don't think I will ever make a feature request. Instead, I think I will ask why the lack of a certain feature is as such.

While the downvotes are kinda proving my point, you should reopen because of

> @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog 'while your main argument about meta sites not having rep is right, what one may run into is the question ban' --> THANK YOU

Comment: Ask your question in the way that is the easiest to interpret/answer. Trying to game it to earn rep or avoid losing it is somewhat counter-productive.

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137097/282094 ----- It is for the question asker to decide what their question is, which in a sense determines what the *correct* answer is, and hopefully voters vote on the question based on the expected voting patterns (which differ on meta sites). **Seperately** it is up to the answerer to write their answer, occasionally leading to an *adjustment* to the question, and hopefully voters vote seperately from the question on the quality of the answer; on its correctness and not political or religious beliefs or preference for a different comp lang.

Comment: This idea applied to tags is not acceptable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43879/282094 - but this question is not a duplicate of that; you are free to phase your question as you see fit, and others can edit it without changing the meaning to clarify or shorten it.

Comment: To me, that question doesn’t mean anything… in the context of SE sites. Unprepared… in what way? What would we be unprepared for? Lack of people interested in participating? Lack of mods? Lack of… purpose? It kinda puts you into a hole where now you have to define everything you want to outline in the question using a “not” to avoid flipping back and forth. It’s not as natural as the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

On site metas voting doesn't affect your reputation, therefore it is not needed to try to avoid downvotes. The reputation that is shown is queried from your main account. This is done precisely because Meta sites involve opinion and you cannot prevent somebody having a different opinion than you by increasing the quality of your posts (although it might help a bit to convince others if you write a very high quality post).

One difference is Meta.SE, which is a 'normal' site in terms of reputation. However, it is not so difficult to collect reputation here because there are a lot of high-traffic posts. For example, my latest answer here on Meta received 12 upvotes, which is much more than almost all of my 800+ answers on my regular site (TeX.SE). Therefore you can also 'afford' to lose some reputation from posting a question or answer with an unpopular opinion.

Comment: *it is not needed to try to avoid downvotes*...while your main argument about meta sites not having rep is right, what one may run into is the question ban. On site metas except Meta Stack Overflow, the thresholds for the ban are the same as that on the main sites; it's only on Meta.SE or Meta.SO that they're adjusted to take into account that downvotes express disagreement.

Comment: Re *"...12 upvotes, which is much more than almost all of my 800+ answers on ... TeX.SE"*: That can't be. [One of them has 35 upvotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383292/all-uses-of-latex-i-never-use-latex-except-for/383314#383314) and the total is more than 120.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I said _almost_ all, I have 8 answers on TeX.SE with 12 or more votes, which is less than 1% of the total number of answers I have on that site.